# Can't access OpenSSL from working directory?

Tags: php, ssl, amazon-web-services, openssl, amazon-ses

So, on my server I'm running several websites. All of my websites, with the exception of my primary one, have the root directory configured to be the 'public' folder of the website (for security purposes). However, one of my nonprimary sites is using Amazon SES to send email, and thus requires OpenSSL to run. Yet I don't believe, with the changed root permissions, the script can find OpenSSL, on the account that I get an error along the lines of:

```
Warning: stream_socket_enable_crypto(): SSL: Success in /public/lib/mailer/class.smtp.php on line 274
2014-05-04 04:52:41 CLIENT -> SERVER: QUIT
2014-05-04 04:52:42 SERVER -> CLIENT: 
2014-05-04 04:52:42 SMTP ERROR: QUIT command failed: 
SMTP connect() failed.
Failed to send the message!
```

every time the script is run. However, when I run the code on the site without the changed root permissions, it runs fine. Is there any way to make my nonprimary websites detect OpenSSL or possibly copy vital OpenSSL files into the root of said websites? Hopefully this is all making sense to you guys. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks. Here's a copy of my email code for anyone interested:

```
$mail = new PHPMailer();

$mail->isSMTP();
$mail->Host = '54.213.255.181'; //IP of AWS SES (email-smtp.us-west-2.amazonaws.com)
$mail->Port = 587;
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';
$mail->Username = 'SMTPUsername'; //Correct
$mail->Password = 'SMTPPassword'; //Correct

$mail->Sender = 'email@domain.com';
$mail->From = 'email@domain.com';
$mail->FromName = "My Name";
$mail->addAddress($to, $fname . " " . $lname);
$mail->SMTPDebug = 2;
$mail->Subject = $subject;
$mail->Body    = $html;  
$mail->AltBody = $msg;
$mail->SmtpClose();

$mail->XMailer = "";
$mail->Encoding = "base64"; 

if(!$mail->send()) {
        $info = 'Failed to send the message!';
    }
    else{
        $info = 'Message has been forwarded to sendmail.';}
        echo $info;  
}
```

Comment: That looks like a success, not a failure. Perhaps you can post the *real* error? And show the code that causes the error, please.

Comment: Take a look... I edited accordingly.

Comment: I think I am running into the same issue using the mailer class in codeigniter.  I have tried using stunnel and that gets me the farthest before throwing an error.